# Is there a way to delete all 1x images in Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

Just like the title says, 1x images are useless in my project now.

Is there any easy way to delete all 1x images at once?

I'm using xcassets to manage my images.

Thanks.

Comment: I face the same issue, have good ideas now?

Comment: @frank You may want to try https://github.com/manicmaniac/xcassets

Comment: thanks, I will try it!

Answer (score -1):

How about to open your project's folder in Finder and find your xcassets folder. Open it and you will find all images and also will be able to remove all you no longer need.

Comment: That's quiet a log of folders and also Contents.json to modify. I can try to write a script but it would be better if there is the other way.